# Order isomorphism on a subset and a segment

Tags: elementary-set-theory, well-orders

I am trying to understand Theorem 1.7.4 of Devlin's Joy of Sets. The Theorem states:

*There is no isomorphism of $X$ onto a segment of $X$* (supposing $X$ is a woset).

The difficulty I am having is that, on the previous page, it is established that a subset, say $Y$, of a set $X$ with an isomorphism $f: X \cong Y$ implies that $\forall x \in X, x \le f(x)$ (Theorem 1.7.2).

Is a segment not also a subset? I understand that Theorem 1.7.2 is conditional on an order isomorphism existing, as it is a premise of the proof. I understand the argument for Theorem 1.7.4 but surely a segment is a subset of a set? It seems like you can construct an isomorphism between $X$ and a segment.

Suppose, $X =$ {$1, 2, 3, 4, 5$} and $X_4 =$ {$1, 2, 3$} is a segment of $X$. Both $X$ and $X_4$ are wosets under the ($\le$) relation.

Now, define $f: X \to X_a$ as a function that maps $1 \to 1, 2 \to 2,$ and $3 \to 3$. Here, $f$ is a bijective function, and it meets the definition of an order isomorphism: $x \lt y \to f(x) \lt ' f(y)$ (in my example the relation between the two sets if the same, so $\lt = \lt '$).

My question then, is why a set cannot have an isomorphism to a segment. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where does $f$ send $4$ and $5$?

Comment: Also, yes a segment is a subset, but not every subset is a segment. So just cause you can have an isomorphism onto a subset doesn't mean you can have an isomorphism onto a segment.

Comment: *Where does f send 4 and 5?* It doesn't, I was under the assumption that an injective function must map elements of the domain to unique elements of the range, so that $s \neq s' \to f(s) \neq f(s')$, and that every element of the range must have an element in the domain. Or, am I mistaken?

Comment: *Also, yes a segment is a subset, but not every subset is a segment. So just cause you can have an isomorphism onto a subset doesn't mean you can have an isomorphism onto a segment.* Thanks! I cannot intuitively understand why though? Is my example incorrect?

Comment: No your last remark is backwards... every element in the domain must be mapped to some element in the range... that's the definition of the domain of a function. If every element of the range is mapped to, that's called being surjective.

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks!